# Go(lang): How to use PPROF heap profile to find memory leaks?

Tags: memory-leaks, go, pprof, heap-profiling

I am trying to use pprof to verify memory leaks.

Can any explain how to read the heap profile that you find at:
`http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap?debug=1`

Also, is it normal that by typing the `web` command after starting `go tool pprof http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap` it produces an empty .svg file?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I may help with the second question. You must provide the name of the binary to your command:

```
go tool pprof YOUR_COMPILED_BINARY http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap
```

Answer (score 1):

How to read the heap-profile is explained pretty good [in this intel blogpost](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703183759/https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs):

> The numbers in the beginning of each entry ("1: 262144 [4: 376832]") represent number of currently live objects, amount of memory occupied by live objects, total number of allocations and amount of memory occupied by all allocations, respectively.

Comment: The Intel website seems to not bother itself with [cool URIs](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html), so here's an [archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703183759/https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs).