# Dumping heap of Go process at runtime

Tags: go, memory-leaks, profiling, heap-memory

We have a `go` process in production using Gigabytes more memory than usual. It's suffered from an unusual memory leak. We stopped input to this process to allow the GC to settle. It is still running with a RES of multiple Gigabytes. Is there a way to attach to this process and dump heap in a way that can be analyzed using hprof visualization tools?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080755/golang-how-to-use-pprof-heap-profile-to-find-memory-leaks / https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-i-investigated-memory-leaks-in-go-using-pprof-on-a-large-codebase-4bec4325e192/#:~:text=WriteHeapDump

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45631 / https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/heapdump15-through-heapdump17

Answer (score 0):

for now, you can use [runtime](http://godoc.org/runtime/pprof) package to write heap profile to a file, and analyze it with [gpreftools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/w/list) visualization tool.

Comment: I have the heap dump file but not sure how to view?